# Django view recieving incomplete POST payload

Tags: python, django, github, payload, pythonanywhere

I have a simple view as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
def stackcommits(request):
    print request.body
    return HttpResponse("")
```

When I POST to the URL mapped to this view, my console shows an incomplete and broken payload. It is about the third of the size it should be, and even then the third that makes it to me is not sequential and delivered in a couple of random pieces. Like follows:

**2014-09-30 18:47:21**
`<QueryDict: {u'payload': [u'{"zen":"Avoid administrative distraction.","hook_id":3103635,"hook":{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/hooks/3103635","test_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/hooks/3103635/test","id":3103635,"name":"web","active":true,"events":["push"],"config":{"secret":"","url":"http://searchdemon.pythonanywhere.com/searchdemon/stackcommits/","content_type":"json","insecure_ssl":"0"},"last_response":{"code":null,"status":"unused","message":null},"updated_at":"2014-09-29T20:56:33Z","created_at":"2014-09-29T20:56:33Z"},"repository":{"id":24075885,"name":"SearchDemon","full_name":"valeyard/SearchDemon","owner":{"login":"valeyard","id":5278331,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/5278331?v=2","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/valeyard","html_url":"https://github.com/valeyard","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/valeyard/followers",`

**2014-09-30 18:47:21**
`.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/issues{/number}","pulls_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/pulls{/number}","milestones_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/milestones{/number}","notifications_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/notifications{?since,all,participating}","labels_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/labels{/name}","releases_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/valeyard/SearchDemon/releases{/id}","created_at":"2014-09-15T22:10:54Z","updated_at":"2014-09-24T17:12:44Z","pushed_at":"2014-09-29T20:42:34Z","git_url":"git://github.com/valeyard/SearchDemon.git","ssh_url":"git@github.com:valeyard/SearchDemon.git","clone_url":"https://github.com/valeyard/SearchDemon.git","svn_url":"https://github.com/valeyard/SearchDemon","homepage":null,"size":1172,"stargazers_count":0,"watchers_count":0,"language":"Python","has_issues":true,"has_downloads":tr`

Any ideas? I have been told that it is not an infrastructure problem at PA, so it is most likely something on my end. But I have no idea what

Comment: how are you posting? Could you post some code of what/how you're posting.

Comment: Yeah sure thing, it is Github webhook POSTs, I have tested that Github are sending them properly by using the following:

http://requestb.in/qhgo7nqh?inspect

you can see the payload being sent from Github there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just seeing a logging artifact. The message is being delivered as a single POST, but the logger is breaking up the message because it is too long. Instead of just `print`ing the message (which sends it to the server log), use `print >> sys.stderr, request.body` and it will appear in the error log without truncation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your print statement is truncating the output of the str(request.body) that happens implicitly, but the actual content of the POST is there. Try this:

```
import pprint

@csrf_exempt
def stackcommits(request):
    pprint.pprint(request.body)
    return HttpResponse("")
```

Comment: Just tried that out, but still appears to be doing the same. When I make Github use the urlencode header (as apposed to json) I seem to consistently get 3 seperate chunks appearing in the server log when I print. I get the start, somewhere in the middle, and then the end of the request. But there is lots randomly missing in between. Can you think of any other way to test whether my server is receiving the data properly?